# Fetch data from database mysql according to today's day? php

Tags: php

Database entry

```
In Database Row Day = {Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday}
```

PHP code

```
$today = date('l');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alert WHERE Day = '$today' ");
```

I want to know how can I fetch data from MySQL database  according to today's day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alert WHERE  FORMAT(Now(),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS PerDate =  FORMAT(your_col,'YYYY-MM-DD') ");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alert WHERE Day = DAYNAME('2008-05-15')");
```

for more info http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayname-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<?php


$jd=cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
$today=jddayofweek($jd,1);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alert WHERE Day = '$today' ");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$today = date('l'); // get day of week today;(its 'L' in lowercase)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alert WHERE Day = '{$today}' ");
?>
```